# Custom space types in Open Atrium

Tags: distributions

I have seen the OA webinar on extending Open Atrium that documented how to make custom content types for sections and have them be recognized and tie in to the OA hierarchy. I would like to do the same but with spaces.

I can clone the space content type to get different ones like "department" or "project" with different custom fields but I want them treated separately in the navbar/breadcrumb.  In other words, the label "space" isn't useful - can't sell that to my client.  Having departments and projects all lumped together as spaces is awkward and too generic.

As far as I can see spaces are OG groups and you can make custom OG groups, but OA builds a complex hierarchy with permissions inheritances and such so not sure if it's possible.

The label "space" and such are hardcoded into the oa breadcrumb module so it appears there's no flexibility and this may require substantial rejiggering of the architecture.

Is there a way to override the default breadcrumb toolbar using the Panels Breadcrumb module (part of the OA distro)?  Can I just roll my own navbar and disable the oa specific module?

Comment: I am looking for something similar - changing the default space type. From what I know this is possible and OA will automatically (based on fields) recognise a new "space like" content type and will work correctly with it. The question is if that is actually a "good practice" and so will not be broken in the next update. About the "space" label, have you checked the taxonomy? There are also blueprints and templates in OA maybe they will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2295541

Short answer: You can't create your own space content types because it breaks the architecture set up by organic groups. Better to use the stock space content type and add a term reference field where the terms delineate different space "types", or make use of the standard "space type" term reference field.